# Fastest way to find out if a repo has any changes using libgit2

Tags: git, libgit2

I want to find the fastest way of determining if anything has changed to a repo. With that I mean if `git status` would show anything else than `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

I know about `git_status_list_new` but it takes about 0.1 seconds on the repo I am trying it on which is a bit too long. Is there some other function that is faster and also works?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think `git_status_list_new` is doing that you don't need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git_diff_tree_to_index` and `git_diff_index_to_workdir` and pass a notify callback to cancel the diff after the first changed file is found.

Of course, in the worst case, where nothing has changed, this isn't any faster than git_status_list_new.